# Postgres Hibernate: Delete existing entity with where and insert new in single transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, java-8, sqlexception

I have a table where I have a composite primary key. Here the combination of sensor and subsystem should be unique. On each insert I want to delete the existing entries based on the mid in a single transaction. I am using hibernate and postgres. Every Time I am trying to save getting a duplicate key violation even when I am trying to delete it first because it is happening in the same transaction. Please suggest a convenient solution. (Don't want to introduce any temp tables or something).

PS: on conflict will not serve the purpose in this case as first i want to remove all the existing entries for mid.

```
CREATE TABLE public.abc (
        id int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('abc_id_seq'::regclass),
        mid int8 NOT NULL,
        nsid int8 NOT NULL,
        sensor text NOT NULL,
        subsystem text NOT NULL,
        mapped_by_user text NOT NULL,
        creation_time timestamp NOT NULL,
        modification_time timestamp NOT NULL,
        obj_version int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        CONSTRAINT abc_pkey PRIMARY KEY (sensor,subsystem),
        CONSTRAINT fk_abckey FOREIGN KEY (mid,nsid) REFERENCES public.def(mid,nsid)
    )
    
             
    
         abcRepository.delete(nid);
         abcRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
```